# *args in function with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I was trying to define a simple sum function in python.

My code is:

```
def sum_all_num(*args):
    return sum(*args)
```

But I got error.  I understand the *args will gather all arguments in a tuple, but why I can not use sum function to sum it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) takes an iterable.  Just remove the `*` and pass the `args` tuple directly.

#### Example:

```
x = 1, 2, 3
print(sum(x))
```

#### Results:

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` takes only one argument (an iterable).

So, instead of unpacking `args` with `*`, just pass the `args` variable to it:

```
def sum_all_num(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

Test:

```
>>> sum_all_num(1,2,3)
6
```

Comment: `sum()` can take two arguments.